# How to get a value in a row when searching in a Database in delphi?

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010

I have located the UserID I want in my database but I want to search for the user's PIN in that same row -- is it possible?

I'm using:

```
tbl1.locate('Column-name' , *Search value*, []);
```

Now I want to get the value of the userpin column in that same row.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having difficulty understanding what you are asking when you say "Now i want to search in the userpin column in that same row!" because you don't need to search for it because you're already on the row.  Are you asking how to get the value of the UserPin for the current row?  If yes use tbl1.FieldByName('userpin') or whatever the column is called.

Comment: Sorry was in a hurry. THanks for the help. I just wanted to locate a unique username in a Column and then if that name was in Row 16 i wanted to search in that row(16) for the unique UserName's pin to compare it to the entered(editbox) pin value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use `TQuery` for this:

```
var Query : TQuery;
    PIN   : string;

begin
  Query.Sql.Text := 'SELECT pin FROM table WHERE id = value'
  Query.Open;
  PIN :+ Query.FieldByName('pin').AsString;
  Query.Close
end;
```

Using the `Locate` is also OK (together with `FieldByName`), but I prefer to use it only to select the row in an `TDBGrid`.

Comment: With respect, no it's not (better that is).  Please re-read the question: The OP wasn't asking how to find a row with a given userpin, but rather how to get the value in the userpin field of the current row.  Btw, your code will just return the pin value in whatever happens to be the first row in the query result set.